# Print field from function

Tags: perl

Perl code:

```
sub fun {
    my $id = { name        => "123",
               full_name   => "345"
               };
    return $id;
}

my $var = fun();
print(...)
```

How can I print the **name** and **full_name**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function returns a reference to a hash.  You need to [dereference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Arrow-Notation) the keys you are interested in:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub fun {
    my $id = { name        => "123",
               full_name   => "345"
             };
    return $id;
}

my $var = fun();
print $var->{name}, "\n";
print $var->{full_name}, "\n";
```